# ReacJS not rendering component on iOS 9 iPad

Tags: reactjs, ios9, mobile-safari, polyfills, shim

I'm unable to run my ReactJS app on iOS 9.3.5 iPad, it just shows a blank screen. I've tried shim and polyfill, not working either. Since is an iPad, I'm not able to extract the error message or other possible logs.

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.14/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.14/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.5/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.5/es6-sham.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you get solution?

Comment: Nope, we end up dropping support for iOS 9

Comment: Ok, i integrated sentry and found out that Intl is causing issue since it doesn't support older version of safari., so i think polyfill will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your component worked before on iOS, it can be one of the last changes you have made, such as one of the packages you have installed that is now making it to not render anymore.

I had the same issue with iOS specifically, my project was rendering normally on Windows and on Android but a NPM package that I installed and its dependencies were making it render a blank screen on iOS.

Try uninstalling the last NPM packages you have installed with all its dependencies using this command:

```
npm uninstall *package-name* --save
```